# How to apply a list of patterns to a dataset in R

Tags: r, design-patterns, replace

all.

I've met the case when I need to clean up a dataset. Specifically, I need to clean up EVTYPE variable with list of patterns.
Anyone knows ways to resolve that?

I have a dtaset:

```
> str(truncData)
'data.frame':   902297 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ STATE__    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ EVTYPE     : Factor w/ 985 levels "   HIGH SURF ADVISORY",..: 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 ...
 $ FATALITIES : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ INJURIES   : num  15 0 2 2 2 6 1 0 14 0 ...
 $ PROPDMG    : num  25000 2500 25000 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 25000 25000 ...
 $ CROPDMG    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sum.inj.fat: num  15 0 2 2 2 6 1 0 15 0 ...
 $ sum.dmg    : num  25000 2500 25000 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 25000 25000 ...
```

EVTYPE field has messy data and it happens that the same Events have different values due to uppercase, lowercase, spaces used incorrectly while data was put into the system.
I have a standard list of event types which I used to create a list of patterns

```
                     EVTYPE DESIGNATOR                pattern
1 Astronomical Low Tide          Z ^Astronomical Low Tide
2           Avalanche            Z           ^Avalanche  
3            Blizzard            Z            ^Blizzard  
4       Coastal Flood            Z       ^Coastal Flood  
5      Cold/Wind Chill           Z      ^Cold/Wind Chill 
6          Debris Flow           C          ^Debris Flow
```

I've tried to apply the list of patterns to the dataset to define and replace incorrect values. 
It could be really hard exercise but to do it manually the last thing I wish.

I also tried to code a function but the result is not I really expected:

```
find.pattern<- function(dataset, pattern, var.replace) {
        var1 <-  subset(dataset
                        , grepl(pattern
                                , dataset[2]
                                , ignore.case = T 
                                )
                        )
        var1 <- gsub(pattern, var.replace, var1)
        return(var1)
    }
x <- mapply(find.pattern
            ,truncData
            , types.list$pattern
            , types.list$EVTYPE)
```

result is:

```
    > str(x)
List of 48
 $ STATE__    : chr(0) 
 $ EVTYPE     : chr(0) 
 $ FATALITIES : chr(0) 
 $ INJURIES   : chr(0) 
 $ PROPDMG    : chr(0) 
 $ CROPDMG    : chr(0) 
 $ sum.inj.fat: chr(0) 
 $ sum.dmg    : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0) 
 $ NA         : chr(0)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`janitor`](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) package? Maybe it can help

Comment: when you ignore case, spaces cause the problem? then try with trimws()

Comment: `tolower(gsub(" ", "", x))` will remove spaces and convert everything to lower case.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks! your proposal is much easier, at least I don't need to write a function :)